# Changing macOS colour through osascript for "highlight" works, but not for "appearance"

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, applescript

I'm on most recent macOS Ventura. I work on a bash shells script that will adjust bunch of settings for mac macOS through command line.

I see that using `osascript` is much better than old `defaults write whatever` because changes are reflected immediately and I don't have to `killall Finder` or `kilall Dock`.

So I want to change both accent and highlight to default blue.

This works for **highlight** and change is immediately reflected:

```
_task_begin "Set Highlight colour"
osascript -e '
  tell application "System Events"
    tell appearance preferences
      set properties to {highlight color:blue}
    end tell
  end tell
' || _task_nok
_task_ok
```

---

This doesn't work for **appearance** and change is not reflected at all (but no errors):

```
_task_begin "Set Accent colour"
osascript -e '
  tell application "System Events"
    tell appearance preferences
      set properties to {appearance:blue}
    end tell
  end tell
' || _task_nok
_task_ok
```

[image]

However when I run the following code in Script Editor I see `appearance` key with my value but still, everything I see selected in Finder + sidebar icons are pink.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

edit:

When I call `defaults write -g AppleAccentColor -string 4` this changes accent  correctly to blue in the appearance window but change is still not applied (even after killing Finder).